# rounded corner imageview programmatically

Tags: android, imageview, rounded-corners

I want to set a rounded corner on my ImageView and here is code:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
            frameLayout.setLayoutParams(up);
            layout.addView(frameLayout);

            CardView cardView = new CardView(this);
            cardView.setCardElevation(0);
            cardView.setRadius(20);
            cardView.setMaxCardElevation(0);
            cardView.setLayoutParams(upz);
            frameLayout.addView(cardView);

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            String imageuri = listgambarpromo.get(i);
            if (!this.isFinishing()) {
                Glide.with(getBaseContext())
                        .load(imageuri)
                        .error(R.drawable.promoe)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.promoe)
                        .skipMemoryCache(true)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .fitCenter()
                        .into(imageView);
            }
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(upz1);
            cardView.addView(imageView);
```

I've set the ImageView inside the CardView, but it doesn't work and shown square on the corners

What should I do with my codes?

Comment: @AliEid the images are square, so I set the CardView with radius

Comment: Do you see the rounded corner cardview? If not, try setting a background to it to make sure it is rounded!

Comment: @AliEid I see my cardview with its rounded corners when I set the imageview with smaller size. But when I set the imageview with matchparent for its width, it becomes square..

Comment: Then you need to add the image to card view itself not the whole frame layout

Comment: @AliEid sorry I edit my codes, but still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already use Glide library for image. So there is make round option

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .apply(new RequestOptions().transforms(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(20)))
    .into(imageView);
```

like this.

if you want to make circle,

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .circleCrop()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.img_nonemymenu)
                    .error(R.drawable.img_nonemymenu);

Glide.with(mContext).setDefaultRequestOptions(options)
    .load(url)
    .circleCrop()
    .into(imageView);
```

like this.

for more options, check [this](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/)

Comment: Thanks bro, it works! so I don't need the cardview anymore if I add the round option ?

Comment: If your cardView contain only ImageView, I think you don't need. But if it contain other Views, maybe you don't need. it's up to you (or your designer)